# SelectMany on an IQueryable ignores conditions?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, iqueryable, lambda

I'm trying to use SelectMany to evaluate a first query with conditions, based on those results execute another query.  I've been told that SelectMany should be able to do this.  The problem I'm having is the SelectMany seems to ignore the conditions in the first lambda expression.  My problem may be with the first expression but I'm not really sure.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong.

First

```
  //get source based on user and active flag
  var query = _sourceRepository.GetTable().Where(s => s.ActionItemStates.Any(ais => ais.UserId == user.Id && ais.IsActive == active));
```

Second - ignores conditions in first

```
var queryActionItems = query.SelectMany(x => x.ActionItemStates).OrderBy(x => x.ActionItem.SortOrder);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your first query doesn't assert that all `ActionItemStates` will have your userId and IsActive true.

It just mean : select me all the `Sources` where *AT LEAST ONE* `ActionItemState` fulfills  my conditions.

But in the second query, `ActionItemStates` are no longer submitted to your conditions : your just taking all `ActionItemStates` from the `Sources` selected in the first query.

First query makes a selection between `Sources`, not between `ActionItemStates`.

Now, this is just explaining WHY it doesn't work, a real answer would need you to explain clearly what you wanna retrieve !

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I figured it might be a problem with the .Any statement.  So if I just wanted the ActionItemStates that correspond to the conditions what would I need to change?

Comment: @NullReference  
if you need your first query, you'll need to "re-add" your conditions in the second. But in this case, the first query... becomes useless (for that part at least) !